# avoid wordpress plugin file caching during development

Tags: caching, plugins, wordpress

I noticed that changes made strictly to plugin file does not instantly available after plugin page refreshing in /wp-admin/ and thus I suspect the object caching is taking place, as the blog itself does not have any caching plugin installed.

is there any way to disable caching for my plugin during development process ?

tried:

```
wp_cache_flush();
```

Comment: You must call the function `wp_cache_flush();`
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/289478/133836

Comment: I have tried just about everything over the last year or so. Did you ever figure it out?
Tried `define('WP_CACHE', 'false');`, `$wp_object_cache->flush();`, and many more.
Ended up with a very hacked process of hosting the plugin directory with an http server and pulling the files in that way, when running locally, but now that development is going to start picking up more, this wont suffice as the complexity of the plugin grows.

Answer (score -1):

Try in your url after your website this "/?ngg_force_update=1" so your url becomes something like:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/?ngg_force_update=1